# How to push a commit to someone else's private repo? (I have the collaborative access)

Tags: git, github

I am working on a collaborative project and project files are in a private repository of the company, which added me as a collaborator. (Say repository name is "Project-A" under the account of "Company_A" in GitHub)

I cloned a .ipynb notebook from a specific branch, (say branch "EDA") and I made some changes to it on my local computer.
I committed the change in my local repo.

How can I push this change to that .ipynb file in repo "Project-A", branch "EDA" using Git?

Comment: Have you create the branch `EDA`? If yes, you must set the upstream: `git push --set-upstream origin <local-branch-name>`. If no, you can only `git push` the committed changes.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen No. My company created that branch. I cloned only that branch to my laptop and made changes.

Comment: So execute just `git push`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should be able to just push it with `git push`. However, since you ask I assume it doesn't work for you, so I would do following troubleshooting:

1. Type `git remote -v` to check, if correct remote repository (Company_A/Project-A) is added as `origin` (if not - `git remote add orign http://...`)
2. Type `git branch -vv` to check, if your `EDA` branch is tracking `origin/EDA` (if not, `git push --set-upstream origin EDA`)

If that doesn't work, it'd be useful to state exact error you get on `git push`